# Is is necessary to learn digital signal processing before starting research in digital image restoration?

Tags: image-processing

I am going to start my research on digital image restoration, I just want to know that should i learn the course **digital signal processing** before starting my research.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My advice would be: do not delay the start of your research, but integrate the study of signal processing basics in the time you have for your research. Basic signal processing knowledge is essential for a proper understanding of the methods of digital image restoration. Divide your time between learning any basic knowledge you might be missing, and studying specific literature on image restoration.